# Selecting all rows where one field contains the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get the following data out of a table like this:

[image: Example Table]

Select all rows where `User = "Ashley" or User = "Barney"` and `SomeID` is equal on both rows. I basically need to get all customers where Ashley *and* Barney are listed as salesmen but not only Ashley or only Barney. Both of them.

**I have no idea what value `SomeID` contains!** The only input I have available is "Ashley" and "Barney".

Is there a way to solve this in (Microsoft) SQL? I have tried working with `GROUP BY` but it does not really help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE SomeID IN (
                   SELECT SomeID
                     FROM MyTable
                    WHERE Salesman IN ('Ashley','Barney')
                 GROUP BY SomeID
                   HAVING count(distinct Salesman) = 2
                 )
```

Here a [demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10aed/1).

Answer (score 2):

To get the IDs, you can use a having-clause with a conditional count for each Salesman value:

```
select SomeID
from MyTable
group by SomeID
having count(case when Salesman = 'Ashley' then 1 else null end) > 0
and count(case when Salesman = 'Barney' then 1 else null end) > 0
```

Selecting the entire row is then as easy as joining on this query:

```
select MyTable.Customer, MyTable.Salesman, MyTable.SomeID
from MyTable
join (
    select SomeID
    from MyTable
    group by SomeID
    having count(case when Salesman = 'Ashley' then 1 else null end) > 0
    and count(case when Salesman = 'Barney' then 1 else null end) > 0
) x on MyTable.SomeID = x.SomeID
```

Comment: I think we can change this to do Salesman IN ('Ashley','Barney') and not have two different case statements

Comment: @rs. The reason I don't do this is because we don't know {SomeID, Salesman} is unique. For example, if we have two rows for Ashley but none for Barney, we don't want to select the row.

Comment: aah yes, that's true about multiple rows with same value